# Keyboard events simulation

Tags: javascript, input, user-input, browser-security, javascript-security

Hey I am interested in learning web development and hacking into sites to see how they implement their security mechanisms. I stumbled upon a ticketing website that has a login, I am trying to log in using JavaScript code that will enter the input value of the email and password.

Here's an example of the login page: [Ticketmaster](https://auth.ticketmaster.com/as/authorization.oauth2?client_id=8bf7204a7e97.web.ticketmaster.us&response_type=code&scope=openid%20profile%20phone%20email%20tm&redirect_uri=https://identity.ticketmaster.com/exchange&visualPresets=tm&lang=en-us&placementId=discovery&hideLeftPanel=false&integratorId=prd1224.ccpDiscovery&intSiteToken=tm-us&deviceId=QjHLxA9Hcb24uLzFuMa8xrq6vLzsiH70Uz5iKQ)

When I try to modify the input values using this code it seems to be not working **By not working I mean when you click sign in it'll empty the fields.**:

```
document.querySelector("[name=email]").value = "test@gmail.com"
document.querySelector("[name=password]").value = "password123A@"
```

I try to do that in the console (by pressing F12). I even went crazy and dispatched all the different types of events. They seem to identify somehow that my events are driven by code. I am curious of how they implemented such methodology and how can I implement in my website.

example for dispatching an event on input to simulate user changing input.

```
document.querySelector("[name=email]").dispatchEvent(new Event("change"))
```

When changing the value you'll see that the value is changed but once you try to focus/blur from the input element, the value will just disappear...

Answer (score 0):

I've just tried it and it works perfectly fine on the example website.

[image: My attempt of your code using Google Chrome console.]

Comment: Try to click sign in button, sorry if my question wasn't clear enough. Please upvote my post if you find it interesting.

Answer (score 0):

If I was to implement such security integrity, I'd probably try checking that the input came from keyboard keypress only.

Comment: How can that be possible, would you elaborate ?

Comment: Using the onKeyDown event. Check that input is happening with this event. I don't really have the algorithm but from the top of my head, under the onChange event detect if keyDown else suspicious input.

Comment: Gotcha, I researched a lot in this topic and I will edit to make a detailed post for whom interested.